# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv (from versions: none)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, module, pycharm

I'm trying to install the `csv` module in Python 3. I have `pip` install, and I'm using Pycharm. I've tried downloading it in the terminal using both `pip install csv` and `pip3 install csv`, but neither of those worked. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for csv
```

I also tried downloading `csv` by going to Pycharm's setting and adding `csv` as a project interpreter, but it gives me the same error message. Hopefully, you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't install the `csv` module because it is already part of Python, so you can just start to use it by including in your file: `import csv`

---

.

Answer (score 2):

csv module is already present as default package in python.
just use it as follows:

```
import csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not name your python project file csv.py